# Which SE site is appropriate to ask how to deal with a medical professional/office?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about how, as a patient, to handle a primary care physician who is being extremely rude and unprofessional, and how to "go above" their office (as the office administrator largely takes the physician's word as gospel and ignores complaints). Which SE site would be most appropriate for this question?

There doesn't seem to be a "medical" SE (and for very good reason I think), but I'm not sure if this falls in the scope of the "workplace" SE since it's not in a work/coworker/etc context or if there's a more appropriate place for it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How is this *not* in a work/coworker/etc. context?

Comment: Because this is an issue as a patient dealing with a doctor and their associated medical office, not as an employee of said office. If you still think it fits there, by all means say so. I'm just trying to find out if that's the best place for it, or if there is a more appropriate SE site for the question.

Comment: Ohh, my apologies, I didn't catch the "patient" part. Yes, that makes a lot more sense. Hmm, that is a tough one. I'll think some more about it. No, Workplace wouldn't be appropriate for that. I thought you worked there, but yes, that makes more sense in retrospect. My bad! :)

Comment: Sorry, from the point of view of the patient I didn't realize that my question didn't appropriately clarify that this was an issue with a patient-doctor relationship! Edited for clarity, thanks!

Comment: There actually is a [Heath.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=qwrUVaBRsf5QmED-qdK94Q2) proposal, but i don't think this would be on topic there either.

Answer (score 1):

The site didn't exist when this question was asked, but I think [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) would fit, as long as you frame it as a question with a [specific goal](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/are-what-should-i-do-questions-on-topic-here). As always, please [search](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search) before asking, and read their [Help Center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to make sure your question is in a good shape.